# Exclude ts files when building using nx

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx

I created nx workspace with typescript library and swc compiler. The folder hierarchy looks like

```
packages/
  my-lib/
    src/
      lib/
        source-file.ts
    test/
      specs/
        source-file.spec.ts
      helper.ts
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.lib.json
    tsconfig.spec.json
```

When I ran `npx nx build my-lib` I found `helper.ts` under `test` folder was compiled which should be excluded.

But it still there even though I added `test/**/*.ts` in `exclude` section in the `tsconfig.lib.json`.

How can I exclude all ts files from `test` folder?

***Update***

If I switched to `tsc` it works as expected (files in `src` folder). But when I use `swc` all files compiled so I think this is something related with `swc`.

Comment: i think ```exclude: [ 'node_modules/',  'tests/' ]``` should be enough.

Comment: @bogdanoff no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. Since I'm using `swc` as the compiler it seems that I must use swc config file, which is `.lib.swcrc` rather than `tsconfig.json`.

I need to add `test` section in `.lib.swcrc` to tell `swc` which folder/files to be compiled, which looks like this

```
{
  "test": [
    "./src/**/.*.ts$"
  ],
  "jsc": {
    // some other config
  }
}
```